# Calculating new column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

While there are some similar questions, I can't find a straightforward answer to the following. Note that I am coming from R, and quite new to Pandas.

Say I have a Pandas dataframe, df, that contains two columns: "measure" (unicode with 3 levels) and "Airquality" (numpy.float64).

I want to create a third column named "color", that is based on values in "Airquality". Further, I want to do this separately for each level of "measure". I have succeeded by splitting the df on "measure" using df.loc. I then calculated "color" separately in each df using the following code:

```
#calculate the maximum value of "Airquality" in df for each "measure" level:
maxi = df['Airquality'].max()

#initialize the column for "color" in df for each "measure" level:
df['color'] = None

#find the maximum value of "Airquality" in df for each "measure" level:
maxi = df['Airquality'].max()

#loop through the rows calculating and assigning the value for color,
#again, in df for each "measure" level
for i in range(len(df['Airquality'])):
    df['color'][i] = int(100*df['Airquality'][i]/maxi)]
```

However, this runs quite slowly with the large dataset I'm working with, and I'm sure there must be a much better way...probably using some Pandas function and likely without splitting the df into three, one for each "measure" level. Posting this in the hopes of learning from one of the many Python geniuses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) tools, in particular `transform`.  Starting from a frame (BTW, it's considered customary to present an example dataframe yourself):

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame({"measure": ["a","a","b","a","c","c"],
    ...:                    "aq": [10,20,30,20,30,50]})

In [22]: df["colour"] = (100.0 * df["aq"] / 
                         df.groupby("measure")["aq"].transform(max))

In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
   aq measure  colour
0  10       a    50.0
1  20       a   100.0
2  30       b   100.0
3  20       a   100.0
4  30       c    60.0
5  50       c   100.0
```

which works because we get the right denominator by grouping on the measure column, finding the maximum of the aq column for each different value of measure, and broadcasting it up to the whole frame, which is what this does:

```
In [24]: df.groupby("measure")["aq"].transform(max)
Out[24]: 
0    20
1    20
2    30
3    20
4    50
5    50
Name: aq, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Awesome, that works (and much faster)! I had something close to that at one point, but never got it working. Not sure how the `.transform(max)` differs from `.max()`, but I'll read into it. Thanks a ton! Oh, and I'll be sure to provide some example data in the future.

Comment: Easiest to try it.  `.max()` gives you a Series with three maximum values, one for each different measure; `.transform(max)` gives you a Series with six values, one for each different row of the original frame, matched up correctly.

Answer (score 24):

I'm hardly a genius, but I'd go with pandas `apply`. Usage i.e. as such:

```
df['newcol'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['firstcolval'] * row['secondcolval'], axis=1)
```

More info in the docs as usual: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at apply a bit. But is there a way to write the code so as to do it separately for the three levels of "measure"? Or do I need to continue with the three separate dataframes? Also, keep in mind that there would be a different value of "maxi" for each level of "measure".

Comment: @davo1979 I don't understand what you mean by splitting "measure"s... Could you provide example data in the question and what the desired output is?